# Making my game start again C#

Tags: c#

so I've made a game as a console application in c#.
Everything's working fine however at the end of the game, the application ends. Instead I want it to ask the user if they would like to play again and re run the game.
Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: check out loops. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e10e56(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your entire program in a loop:

```
while(true) {

    RunGame();

    Console.WriteLine("Play again? Yes|No");
    if( !Console.ReadLine().StartsWith("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ) break;
}
```

Comment: @JohnBoker I'm not a fan of `do/while` because rarely does a condition exactly fit into the closing `while` statement expression.

Comment: at least it's not a goto :)

Comment: A goto would have been the best answer actually :-)

Comment: There would be nothing wrong with a `goto`... it would even compile into the same code.  At least it wasn't an abused `for (;;)` :P

Comment: @Dai, but the pattern you coded in your `while(true) break` is the same pattern as a `do while`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the game logic in a conditional loop.

```
do 
{
   YourGameLogic();
   Console.WriteLine("play again? [yay! | nay!]");
} while(Console.ReadLine() != "nay!");
```